# bicubic bezier patch - trouble with understanding

Tags: matlab, math, 3d, geometry, bezier

I got **bicubic bezier** patch stored as 16 `float3` points

```
float3 bezier[16];
```

those are 4 sets of 4 points

```
{A4 B4 C4 D4} // 4th curve
{A3 B3 C3 D3} //3rd curve
{A2 B2 C2 D2} //2nd curve
{A1 B1 C1 D1} //1st curve
```

alright, i evaluate  points for a given `t, p(t)` where `t` is from `0.0` to `1.0`. This is easy. I use this points like:

```
{1st curve point p0(t=0  ) , 2nd curve point p1(t=0  ), 3rd p2(t=0  ), 4th  p3(t=0  ) }
{1st curve p0(t=0.1) , 2nd p1(t=0.1), 3rd p2(t=0.1), 4th  p3(t=0.1) }
```

to evaluate and draw 'orthogonal' (transverse) curves.

I am not able to understand one thing, those control points B, C for first base curves are control points and as far as I understood don't lay on the surface. Those all evaluated `p(t)` on four base curves lays on the surface* , I use them then to evaluate the orthogonal curves (sorta like orthogonal `A' B' C' D'`) and then evaluated `q(t)` values I use to draw the path

Yet in short to be for sure understood:

I use four `{A, B, C, D}` sets to evaluate four `p(t)` curves
 `t` is taken with step like 1/30, thirty steps; then I take those `p(t)` points as a `{A' B' C' D'}`  to evaluate `q(t)` orthogonal/transverse curves

Thing I am not able to understood is:

if `B,C` in base curves don't lay on the surface, why in the second step I take `p2(t), p3(t)` points. If they lay on the surface as a `B' C'` control points?

Isn't it inconsistent?

Or maybe evaluated `p[1,2](t)` don't lay on the surface either - but if so why all transverse evaluated `q(t)` are laying on the surface where evaluated `p(t)` are not laying? Isn't it inconsistent?  if I evaluate in `p`-direction I got virtual points and if I evaluate in `q` direction I got real points ?

Can someone explain this?

Comment: How is that you evalueate 30 points in step 1, but use only 4 in step 2? Anyway, you cant use the points in step 1 as control points in step 2, if you are using Bezier curves.

Comment: In step one i evaluate four curves (for say, 30 points evaluated on each), name them p0(t), p1(t), p2(t), p3(t) - they are evaluated on the base four sets of control points ... In second step i take those 30 * 4 points to evaluate 30 q(t) curves (which i also evaluate with 30 steps, say i got then final 900 quads to draw)

Comment: And that is wrong. As I said, you can not use a point in the surface as control point for evaluating a curve! The result will be wrong.

Comment: But it works - i rendered utah teapot (taking this raw data http://www.sjbaker.org/wiki/index.php?title=The_History_of_The_Teapot  ) with this and it has not any visible distortion

Comment: I wouldnt like to revrite code if not need - if i could manage understood if this is proper way or not

Comment: It works wrong. The teapot will be rendered and will look like a teapot, but it will be smaller (see my drawing bellow, if the black points are in the surface, then the surface will look similar, but it will be "lower"). Probably that teapot also has A LOT of patches, thus making the errors less noticeable. Still, it is wrong.

Comment: I repeat: Bezier curve control points WILL NOT be on the curve, or vice versa, th ecurve created will not go through the Bezier points. Thats why sometimes alternative surfaces are used, such as splines, because the points ARE in the surface. There is no way around this, If you want Bezier surfaces, you MUST use the equations on my answer.

Comment: Also, If you are using the vertices of the teapot as control points, that is wrong also!

Comment: well if so that is good comment.. tnx.. do you know maybe some example of c code in net that could take float4 bezier[16] as input and would yeild to DrawQuad calls - maybe? If so i will ned to repair that..  Does you maybe know if such two phases method (first calculate vertical virtual curves used to calculate finel real ones )is possible with some modifications? (This way i could reduce calculating patch to calculating curves what was handy

Comment: Use spline surfaces, that way you can separate the evaluation.

Comment: but teapot wont rune on splines? maybe i revrite to proper form will be easier

Comment: You can use any of the thousands of different surface representations to draw it. AFAIK, th emodels are no tin anything, they just give you vertices and faces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand where are you stuck, but Bezier surface control points do not lie in the surface itself (well, not all of them, the 4 corners do).

[image]

To evaluate a point on a Bezier surface you need those control points, but you need them to plug them into the Bezier surface equation. There are 2 main ways of describing the equation: analytic form and matrix form.

---

## Analitic form

the one that wikipedia shows:

[image]

[image]

where **K** are your control points, and u,v go from 0 to 1.

---

## Matrix form

[image]

Where the matrices are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In this case P are control points but u,v are also from 0 to 1.

---

You can choose either of them to compute any point in the surface, just by evaluating the equations for a given 12 control points and a chosen u,v pair.

Source: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/AV0405/DONAVANIK/bezier.html

Comment: heh you beat me while I eddited question :) (+1) nice image for this

Comment: @Spektre hey your answers are generally quite good, you may want to post it anyways!

Comment: I use different method see the comment below question - may repaste "In step one i evaluate four curves (for say, 30 points evaluated on each), name them p0(t), p1(t), p2(t), p3(t) - they are evaluated on the base four sets of control points ... In second step i take those 30 * 4 points to evaluate 30 q(t) curves (which i also evaluate with 30 steps, say i got then final 900 quads to draw) " - is this code wrong? It seem to me be a bit logically inconsistent but im not sure

Comment: (you may imagine four p(t) curves are more horizontal on image, and then 30 q(t) final curves (whose 900 points i use then to draw quads) i calculate are more vertical ones (depending on the position of the eye) - I use four horizontal to calc 30 vertical